# Cubic roots of determinant.

Tags: roots, determinant, cubics

If x=a+2b satisfies the cubic (a,b element of R) f(x)= 
$$\left|\begin{matrix} a-x & b & b \\ b & a-x & b \\ b & b & a-x\end{matrix}\right|$$
=0, then it's other 2 roots are?

Comment: The determinant gives a third order polynomial whose first root you already know. How can you obtain a second order polynomial from it?

Comment: @juanrapha: I can obtain a second degree polynomial by dividing the equation with its given root. But are there any SMART solution or other solution of this problem? Can it be solved using some different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of this determinant are the [eigenvalues of a circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues) with row $[a \ b \ b ]$ and so are given by $a+b\omega^k + b\omega^{2k}$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cubic root of unity. Hence, they are $a+b+b=a+2b$ (for $k=0$) and $a+b(\omega+\omega^2)=a-b$ (for $k=1,2$).

Comment: How can we know by oberving a problem that it can be solved using this method?

Comment: @Adarsh, the matrix given is of the form $C-xI$, where $C$ is a circulant matrix.

Comment: Okay. Got it, but how to know what values of k we've got to put in. Like in this specific problem you put 3 values of k. Does it depends on the order of polynomial?

Comment: @Adarsh, in general, $\omega$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, so $n$ values.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=(a-x)^3+2b^3-3b^2(a-x)=0$$
putting $y=a-x$ you get
$$y^3-3b^2 y+2b^3=0\ ,$$
you know that $y=-2b$ is a solution, so
$$y^3-3b^2 y+2b^3=(y+2b)(y-b)^2\ .$$
The other solutions are thus $y=b$, i.e. $x=a-b$.

Comment: Brother how did you made the cubic equation so efficiently? I struggle to make the cubic equations as beautifully as you've made. Tell me some methods of achieving this beauty and arrangement in equation.

Comment: I brutally used polynomial division...